# Can I take an overnight bag into the theatre / cinema in London?

Tags: luggage, london, luggage-storage, cinema

I'm travelling to London in early November for an overnight trip, during which I'm visiting the Odeon in Leicester Square and the Apollo Victoria.

Will I have any problems taking a small overnight bag into either of these places, and if so, where would the nearest luggage drops be?

Comment: FWIW, since [asking if this would be on topic on Travel](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3469/i-have-a-question-related-to-a-trip-to-london-is-it-on-topic-for-travel), I also got a reply from Odeon [via twitter](https://twitter.com/ODEONHelp/status/654590710868520961), but I'd still be interested in actual experiences.

Comment: You should turn that tweet into an answer. I don't think you'll get anything better or more official than that.

Comment: @Flimzy Done!  And for some reason I hadn't even thought of tweeting the apollo... now done also... :)

Comment: Idk how relevant this is, but for a period after the Aurora theatre shooting, the theatre in my area required you to keep your bags at the front desk. They've since quite enforcing it, but it shows that it's just under the  theatre's discretion.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Completely different country...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I posed this question to [@OdeonCinemas](https://twitter.com/ODEONCinemas), [@OdeonHelp](https://twitter.com/ODEONHelp) and [@ApolloVictoria](https://twitter.com/ApolloVictoria) on Twitter and received the following replies from each:

> Provided it doesn't create a trip hazard, or get in the way then there shouldn't be a problem.

-@OdeonCinemas ([source](https://twitter.com/ODEONCinemas/status/654337907340275713))

> As long as it doesn't block any aisles you will be fine :)

-@OdeonHelp ([source](https://twitter.com/ODEONHelp/status/654590710868520961))

So small bags in the Odeon appear to be fine. And the Apollo has a cloakroom:

> Hi James we have a cloakroom you can put your bag in!!

-@ApolloVictoria ([source](https://twitter.com/ApolloVictoria/status/654684170313035778))

---

*Update*: Having now visited, I can confirm that my small backpack wasn't even given a second glance at either venue.

Comment: Here you go: on topic question + well received by the community = easy reputation. :)

Comment: @JoErNanO Yeah - fastest rep I've gained on the network so far :)

Answer (score 12):

In case your luggage is really really big, and would be considered a trip hazard (in Odeon), then your nearest luggage storage area would be Charing Cross Station, where there is a [Left Luggage station](http://www.left-baggage.co.uk/stations). It is open between 7:00 and 23:00, so you won't have access to your luggage between 23 and 7 at night meaning anything you'd need during night you have to put in a smaller bag which you have to bring with you to the cinema.

Also if you are arriving and leaving London via train or plane, other central stations in London have similar facilities as well, so it might be easier to drop them off at the station you are leaving from.

For prices check the link, where you can pre-book space for your luggage, it is not cheap though, as an overnight price for 24h storage is around £11.

Answer (score -1):

I don't there will be any problem if you have small bag. Yes, If you have a bag pack luggage while visiting any attraction, then there should be an issue. So if you are moving around any London Icon, then keep your bag small.